# How should I connect to an FTP server from Mathematica running under Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, url, http-functions

I found relevant information on the problem for Linux or MacOS, but I run programmes under Windows.

I want to connect to a friend's FTP server to download some files. Of course the server has wants a username and password, and my friend offered me this.

At the beginning, I tried to use `Import` like this:

```
Import["username:passward@ftp://ip_address/diretory/filename"]
```

Mathematica tells me that it is not a effective filename.

Another friend tells me to move username and password after ftp, like this:

```
"ftp://username:password@ip_address/directory/filename"
```

Seems it is recognized as a correct file, but I get an error telling me some problem happened at FetchURL. It says

> The server returned the HTTP status code 400 ("Bad Request").

Next I tried another way to use `Import`. Like this:

```
Import[
  "ftp://ip_address/directory/filename", 
  "Username" -> username, "Password" -> password]
```

I got the same response with HTTP 400 Error.

Am I going about trying to make a FTP connection in the wrong way?

Could I get some help so I can successfully download a file form ftp server?

Comment: Have a look at `CopyFile` and `RemoteFile` and see if that might help you.

Comment: What happens if you try to open the URL "ftp://username:password@ip_address/directory/filename" in a browser?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi
It opens as i expected,and nothing happened seems an error